# what mongomapper version for sinatra 1.2.6

Tags: mongodb, sinatra, mongomapper

I use sinatra 1.2.6 and mango_mapper version 0.9.2 but project is slow for render page.How I config mongomapper and sinatra

Comment: Why are you so sure that it's the mongomapper that's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by configuring Mongomapper and Sinatra. I use this in my configure block:

```
MongoMapper.database = ENV['MONGOLAB_DATABASE']
MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new(ENV['MONGOLAB_URL'], 27107)
MongoMapper.database.authenticate(ENV['MONGOLAB_USER'], ENV['MONGOLAB_PASS'])
```

But then this is not just for Sinatra and is pretty much required everywhere. Performance is also ok here. You could check out the rstatus project on Github which uses now Rails but used to be Sinatra. So compare your code with theirs.